# How do I switch to the other side camera of my character?

Tags: ps4, the-last-of-us

In the Last of Us for the PlayStation 4, how do I switch my camera of my character so I can see the other side, like around a door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the PlayStation 4, Press R1 while aiming down your sights to change the camera.

Answer (score 0):

While aiming (*L2* OR *L1*, depending on your settings), tap R1 to shoulder switch. This is useful when running away from a target or when behind cover.